Data is automatically lost after being overwritten when the program is restarted
In my program, I have to overwrite the current data to a CSV file. But after being overwritten, when I launch my program again, those data disappeared.
> public class writeFile {

    private Writer fw;
    public writeFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(fileName, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void writeToCSV(String[] org) {
        String text = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < org.length; i++) {
            text += org[i];
            if(i != org.length - 1) {
                text += ",";
            } else {
                text += "\n";
            }
        }
        try {
            fw.write(text);
            fw.flush();
            //fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

Above is my writeFile class. Can anyone help me to explain and fix it?

shutDown is almost certainly not being called reliably. What are you going to do, btw, if one of your array elements contains one or more commas? You should use a proper CSV writer. btw, class names should be noun-based

Where do you call the method writeToCSV()?

Hello allmight, welcome, you only need change fw = new FileWriter( fileName, false ); to fw = new FileWriter( fileName, true );, and each write will aggregate the data, rather than overwrite it.

I'm assuming you mean "my file is empty". Since you're opening the Writer without appending, I'm assuming you know that anything previous will be overwritten

Just to clear up any confusion: Constructs a FileWriter given the File to write and a boolean indicating whether to append the data written, using the default charset.

If you're determined to home-brew, then maybe: 1: Make your class name a noun, e.g. CsvWriter
2: implement AutoCloseable
3: Don't concatenate a String, write the fields straight out
4: Flush after the line separator
5: Use Files.newBufferedWriter to obtain your Writer

The Answer by Rezaei is correct. In addition I would automatically close the file on every use. There’s no point in keeping the file open.
Auto-close on every use
The FileWriter class implements AutoCloseable. That means we can use try-with-resources syntax to auto-close.
Start your class name with an uppercase letter per Java convention. And choose a more specific descriptive name like CsvWriter.
Generally best to keep your constructors as short, simple, and sweet as possible. If you are needing to catch exceptions, consider a different design.
Better to explicitly state your intended character encoding rather than rely implicitly upon a default. Communicate your intentions to the programmers reading your code later. So use this constructor.
public class CsvWriter {

    // Fields
    private String fileName ;

    // Constructor
    public CsvWriter( final String aFileName ) {
        this.fileName = aFileName ;
    }

    // Behavior
    public void write ( final String[] input ) {
        try
        (
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( this.fileName , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 , true ) ;  // `true` to append to file rather than replace. 
        )
        {
            // write your CSV, call methods on `writer` variable. 
        }
        catch ( … ) { … }
        // The file writer is automatically closed at this point. 
    }
}

Usage:
CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter( … ) ;
csvWriter.write( … ) ;
…
csvWriter.write( … ) ;

This code assumes you are working single-threaded. This code is not thread-safe.
Of course in real work you would leverage one of the good CSV libraries rather than roll-your-own.
